# How can I vectorize the following algorithm?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

Is there a way that I could do vectorization instead of for loop for the following algorithm?

```
def test_func(df):

    idx_lst = [df.index[0]]
    end = df.loc[df.index[0], "end"]

    for idx in df.index[1:]:
        if df.loc[idx, "begin"] > end:

            end = df.loc[idx, "end"]
            idx_lst.append(idx)
    
    return df.loc[idx_lst]
```

test case:

df = pd.DataFrame({"begin":[3,5,7,8,10,12,14], "end":[8,9,10,12,13,14,17]})

```
   begin end
0   3   8
1   5   9
2   7   10
3   8   12
4   10  13
5   12  14
6   14  17
```

test_func(df)

```
   begin end
0   3   8
4   10  13
6   14  17
```

Comment: at first glance this looks hard to vectorize to me, and it looks ripe for using `numba`. but I'm curious to see any solutions

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you for the comment! is it possible to use functions like 'map' to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the earlier comment that it is hard or even impossible to use
vectorization.

But try instead the following function:

```
def myFunc(df):
    arr = df.begin.values > df.end[:, np.newaxis]
    r = 0
    idx_lst = [r]
    while True:
        wrk = np.nonzero(arr[r])[0]
        if wrk.size == 0:
            return df.iloc[idx_lst]
        r = wrk[0]
        idx_lst.append(r)
```

The advantage of my solution is that the "comparison array" (*arr* - whether
*begin* column from some row > *end* column from another row) is computed
in one go.

Another advantage is that there is no need to process each row.

Yet another advantage is that I use *Numpy*, which is known to operate
faster than *Pandas*.

Using *%timeit*, on your source data sample, I stated that my function
takes just the same time to generate the result as yours.

But try it on a greater sample of source data. Maybe my solution will be faster.